# Ubuntu 16.04 Installer Boots Into Black Screen on Intel Atom D2500 Laptop

Tags: boot, system-installation

I have a Samsung 275E4V-K01HK Laptop and I tried to install Ubuntu 16.04 (32-bit) on it. Apparently this laptop will boot directly into black screen after selecting "install" or "try without install" on the boot menu.

I have tried replace `quiet` with `nomodeset` and adding `i915.modeset=1` as well as `vga=915` while activating `nolapic` and `nomodest` on `F6` menu. Still no luck (the error message is `kernel panic: trying to kill init`).

Samsung 275E4V-K01HK has a Intel Atom D2500 dual-core processor and 4GB DDR3 ram. The mainboard has an unknown chipset with the name of 275E4V-K01HK (same as the model number).

Note, Intel does claim D2500's graphic driver (Cedarview) supports Windows 7 32-bit only according to this page: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/graphics-drivers/000005526.html

P.S., it looks like I need to roll back to kernel 3.2 after installation, but the problem is I cannot even install since I cannot boot into the graphic installation interface. I like to know if I can install Ubuntu 16.04 through a command line interface and boot directly into and boot directly into after the installation.

Comment: [Try Fedora](https://getfedora.org/), just testing for. It has later kernel, other Compositor; to exclude it wasn't fixed, or not something specific to Unity.